# set canvas data to an input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to take a picture from the user and send it to the server without ajax.
I searched and found this code that takes the photo from video and draws it on canvas. now I want to set that image to an input on form but I don't know how.
this is HTML code:

```
<video id="player" controls autoplay></video>
<button id="capture" onclick="$('#loader').hide()">Capture</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width=320 height=240></canvas>
<input id="image-input">
```

and this is javascript code :

```
const player = document.getElementById('player');
  const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  const captureButton = document.getElementById('capture');

  const constraints = {
    video: true,
  };

  captureButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Draw the video frame to the canvas.
    context.drawImage(player, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    player.srcObject.getVideoTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
    var Pic = document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL("image/png");
    Pic = Pic.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "")
  });

  // Attach the video stream to the video element and autoplay.
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then((stream) => {
      player.srcObject = stream;
    });
```

now I want to set this image as the image of input.
how can I do that?

Comment: `$("#image-input").val(canvas.toDataURL())` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL

Comment: @freedomn-m I do that but it says :Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.

Comment: Your code as provided in the question (all we have to go on) has `<input id="image-input">` not `<input id="image-input" type='file'>` - if you could provide a "working" snippet that matches your actual code, it would help.  Have a read of [ask] and [mcve].  In the mean time, change to `<input id="image-input" type="text"/>`